# Xamarin forms Application.Current.Properties equivalent in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, xamarin.forms

I would like to know if there is any equivalent of "Application.Current.Properties" in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using one of those (in alphabetical order):

1. [flutter_sqlcipher](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sqlcipher)
2. [get_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage)
3. [localstorage](https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage)
4. [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)
5. [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, finally I was able to solve my problem